# How to copy and change the data format?

Tags: r

How can I copy the data from a column and change its data?

For instance, I have these data below and I want to copy all data in `winddir` into a new data called `wd`, but I want to change any N (North) to 0 (0 degrees) and any S (South) to 180 (180 degrees) and so on,

```
    timestamp   date                winddir 
1   1412877113  09/10/2014 13:51    N   
2   1412876508  09/10/2014 13:41    S
```

so my new data is,

```
    timestamp   date                winddir   wd
1   1412877113  09/10/2014 13:51    N         0 
2   1412876508  09/10/2014 13:41    S         180
```

My working line that copy the column (but I have no idea how to change its data)

```
dat$wd <- dat$winddir
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to work with other directions than just `N` and `S` then you need to nest `ifelse` or a vectorized version hereof. But a vectorized `ifelse` is not readily available. And too many nested `ifelse`s are suboptimal.

However, you can also solve it by `character` indexing like so:

```
# Read in your data
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
timestamp   date                winddir 
1412877113  '09/10/2014 13:51'    N   
1412876508  '09/10/2014 13:41'    S")

# Create a named vector of the degrees
tr <- c(N = 0, NE = 45, E = 90, SE = 135, S = 180, SW = 225, W = 270, NW = 315) 
print(tr)
## N  NE   E  SE   S  SW   W  NW 
## 0  45  90 135 180 225 270 315

# We can then lookup the degrees with characters:
tr["E"]
##  E 
## 90 

tr[c("NE", "SE")]
## NE  SE
## 45 135

# Therefore, we can then use tr to look up the desired directions:
dat$wd <- tr[dat$winddir]
print(dat)
##   timestamp             date winddir  wd
##1 1412877113 09/10/2014 13:51       N   0
##2 1412876508 09/10/2014 13:41       S 180
```

Be sure that `dat$winddir` is a `character`.

This should also work with NE, SW, and so on. It is trivial to expand this to e.g. the 32 cardinal points NbE, NNE, and so on.

**Edit**: Alternatively, you can save your look up in the following equivalent manners:

```
dat <- within(dat, wd <- tr[winddir])
```

or like @agstudy suggests:

```
dat <- transform(dat, wd = tr[winddir])
```

Answer (score 1):

For example using `ifelse`:

```
 dat <- transform(dat,wd= ifelse(windir=="N",0,180)
```